# Interactive change of bgcolor by typing hex values

Tags: html, css

I want to create a page where i can input hex values to change the bacground color in order to test layout

Comment: Cool! Are you having problems with it?

Comment: describe more my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/o8oep7c1/1/)? Using jQuery:

```
$("input").change(function() {
  $('body').css('background', $(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<input type="text" value="#330000" id="color"/>
<button id="changeColor">Change Color</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var button = document.getElementById("changeColor");
button.addEventListener('click', setColor, false);

function setColor(){
  var color = document.getElementById("color").value;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

[See JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yojeya/2/edit)